# Selenium WebDriver: Not able to select the element from the drop down list using webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have two dropdown list in my application, Second dropdown becomes enable after selecting the 1st dropdown. Problem i am facing is my code is able to select the value from the 1st drop down but it is not selecting the value from the 2nd drop down. I am getting error as :

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 138 milliseconds

I have tried wait as well after selecting the 1st dropdown but still getting this error.

My Java code:

Code for 1st dropdown:

```
  WebElement combo= d1.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlAgency"));
  System.out.println("proerty name for agent:" +combo);
  combo.sendKeys("huma");
  //d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   Thread.sleep(200);
```

Code for 2nd drop down:

```
   WebElement combo1=d1.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCountry"));
   System.out.println("proerty name for country:" +combo1);
   combo1.clear();
   combo1.click();
   combo1.sendKeys("Test");
```

HTML for the 2nd dropdown:

```
  <select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCountry" style="width:450px;"       onchange="fillval();" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCountry">
```

Error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 138 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Select` Class for the second dropdown.

```
WebElement combo1 = driver.findElement(By.name(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCountry));
    Select secondDrpDwn = new Select(combo1);
    secondDrpDwn.selectByValue("Test");
```

Comment: Thanks Hemche.I tried your code and now am getting the following error  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with value: Test

Comment: please let me know what else i can do for this.

Comment: I have tried  secondDrpDwn.selectByIndex(4);  
               // secondDrpDwn.selectByVisibleText("Test"); as well but still getting same error " Cannot locate option with ".

Comment: Do you have the option "Test" inside the second dropdown ? Also, if possible, share the html code for the second drop down along with options.

Comment: this is the HTML:  <select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCountry" style="width:450px;" onchange="fillval();" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCountry">
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hide1" type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hide1" value="Test"/>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdfCountryId" type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdfCountryId" value="744"/>

Comment: The option `Test` should be visible before selecting that value.
So, you can use the following code to select the value `Test`.
`d1.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCountry")).click();
d1.findElement(By.id("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hide1")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the work around to my problem. sharing it so that it will help others as well.
following code is working for me.

```
              WebElement dropDownListBox =d1.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"Please Select Country\"]"));
              dropDownListBox.click();

             WebElement    combo1=d1.findElement(By.name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCountry"));
             System.out.println("proerty name for country:" +combo1);
             combo1.click();
             Select secondDrpDwn = new Select(combo1);
             secondDrpDwn.selectByVisibleText("Test");
```